# Building form with dynamic rows

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I make flutter widget equivalent to my below html5 widget?

In my html I've a form in the form of table where only first row appear, then the user can add whatever rows he want, (and can delete any row he want, unless it is the only row in the form) as show:

[image]

The code I'm using is:

```js
<script>
  function deleteRow(row) {
    var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex - 1; // this -> td -> tr // -1 because the first row is used for header
    var tbl = document.querySelector('#dataTable');
    if(tbl && tbl.rows.length > 1) {
      tbl.deleteRow(i); 
      Array.from(tbl.rows).forEach((row, index) => {
        row.cells[0].innerHTML = index + 1;
      });
    }
  } 

  function insRow(row) {
    var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex - 1; // this -> td -> tr // -2 because the first row is used for header
    var tbl = document.querySelector('#dataTable');
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML=`
      <th></th>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" name="color1" /></td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" name="color2" ></td>
      <td><i class="fas fa-edit" onclick="insRow(this)"></i></td>
      <td><i class="fas fa-eraser" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></i></td>
    `;
    var len = tbl.rows.length;
    row.cells[0].innerHTML = len + 1;
    tbl.insertBefore(row, tbl.children[i+1]);
    Array.from(tbl.rows).forEach((row, index) => {
      row.cells[0].innerHTML = index + 1;
    });
    //tbl.appendChild(row);
  }
</script>
```

And the form itself is made with the follwoing html

```html
<form method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>توزيع مبلغ البيان على طلبات الشراء</legend>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>التسلسل</td>
          <th>رقم طلب الشراء</td>
          <th>قيمة فاتورة طلب الشراء</td>
          <th colspan="2">إضافه/حذف</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="dataTable">
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <td><input size=25 type="text" name="color1" /></td>
          <td><input size=25 type="text" name="color2" /></td>
          <td colspan="2"><i class="fas fa-edit" onclick="insRow(this)"></i></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
  <br/>
   <input dir="ltr" type="submit" value="SEND إرسال">
</form>
```

The form is executed from a GO code as:

```golang
// ContactDetails ...
type ContactDetails struct {
    Email   string
    Subject string
    Message string
    Color1  []string
    Color2  []string
}

// ReturnedResult ...
type ReturnedResult struct {
    Result  bool   `json:"result"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles(fmt.Sprintf("%v", "formen.html"))) // index.html
    if r.Method != http.MethodPost {
        tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
        return
    }

    r.ParseForm()
    fmt.Println(r.Form) // print information on server side.
    fmt.Println("path", r.URL.Path)
    fmt.Println("scheme", r.URL.Scheme)

    for k, v := range r.Form {
        fmt.Println("key:", k)
        fmt.Println("val:", v)
    }
    details := ContactDetails{
        Email:   r.FormValue("email"),
        Subject: r.FormValue("subject"),
        Message: r.FormValue("message"),
        Color1:  r.Form["color1"],
        Color2:  r.Form["color2"],
    }
    fmt.Printf("Post from website! r.PostFrom = %v\n", r.PostForm)
    fmt.Printf("Details = %v\n", details)

    //r.FormValue("username")
    fmt.Println()
    // do something with details
    sheetID := "AKfycbxfMucXOzX15tfU4errRSAa9IzuTRbHzvUdRxzzeYnNA8Ynz8LJuBuaMA/exec"
    url := "https://script.google.com/macros/s/" + sheetID + "/exec"
    bytesRepresentation, err := json.Marshal(details)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    resp, err := http.Post(url, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(bytesRepresentation))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    // read all response body
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    // close response body
    resp.Body.Close()

    webReturn := ReturnedResult{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &webReturn); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(webReturn.Message)

    webReturn.Message = strings.ReplaceAll(webReturn.Message, "&export=download", "")
    //tmpl.Execute(w, struct{ Success bool }{webReturn.Result})
    tmpl.Execute(w, webReturn)

}
```

Comment: The key to do this is using: Listview.builder.